# How do I show that the following integral is bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals, continuity

Let $f:[0,1]\mapsto R$ be a continuous function. $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{n}dx$ is bounded. Is it true or false? If it is true prove that the integral is bounded.

I think it might be true since closed and bounded intervals are mapped to closed and bounded intervals under continuous function. But I'm not sure if my reasoning is correct or wrong? Since $f(x)$ is closed and bounded, its definite integral might also be bounded. But  how do I prove it? Any hints are appreciated!

Edit: What about its sequence? Now, I'm trying to prove that $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{n}dx$ is bounded as a sequence. So, I'm trying to prove that it is a Cauchy sequence in R.

My attempt: Consider, $|\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{n}dx-\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{m}dx|\leq |\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{n}dx|+|\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{m}dx|$
Then since each integral is bounded, I can write as $\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{n}dx$<$M$ and $ \int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{m}dx$ <$M'$
Then I can find a delta that satisfies $|\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{n}dx|+|\int_{0}^{1}|f(x)|^{m}dx|$<$M+M'$

Is this way correct?

Comment: You are on the right track. There exists a constant $C>0$ such that $|f(x)|\le C$, thus $|f(x)|^n\le C^n$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then $\int_0^1|f(x)|^n\,\mathrm dx\le\int_0^1C^n\,\mathrm dx$ by “non-decreasingness” of $\int$.

Comment: Are you asking whether each integral $\int_0^1|f(x)|^n\,\mathrm dx$ is bounded? Yes; that's trivial. Or are you asking whether the *sequence* $\left(\int_0^1|f(x)|^n\,\mathrm dx\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded?

Comment: What is the variable here? Are you asking if it is a bounded function of $n$?

Comment: @José Carlos Santos I'm trying to do both. And thanks for answering!

Comment: Uniform boundedness does not hold in general (take e.g. $f\equiv2$).

Comment: @nejimban. Thanks for answering. I'm also trying to prove it as a sequence. I should've mentioned it. Sorry.

Comment: @NatashaJ nejimbam just give you a counterexample

Comment: So it is false, because if we take $f(x)=2$ then, it becomes unbounded?

Comment: @NatashaJ Yes if you are considering it as a sequence.